# How to pass data from one json object to other in Java?

Tags: java, json

this is my initial json object:

```
{
    "user": "user1",
    "twitter": "tweet1",
    "timestamp": 13661506
},
{
    "user": "user2",
    "twitter": "tweet2",
    "timestamp": 13661544
}
```

I need the output json object to be like this:

```
{
    "user":"user1",
    "timestamp": 13661506
},
{
    "user":"user2",
    "timestamp": 13661544
}
```

Here datatype of 'user' is string and 'timestamp' is long. I need to preserve these datatypes in my new object. Is there a way to do this in java?

I tried to use ArrayList to implement this. This is my current method. As you can see it is juvenile and not feasible and I am getting errors.

//data_obj is the json object 
//Choice_array contains the chosen values

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data_array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    int s=0, l=0;
    for(i=0; i< data_obj.length(); i++)'
    { 
      ArrayList<String> data_array_string = new ArrayList<String>();    
      ArrayList<Long> data_array_long = new ArrayList<String>();    
      for(i1=0; i1< choice_array.length(); i1++)
      {
        Object myObj = data_obj.get(i);
        if(myObj instanceof Long)
        {
          data_array_long.add(data_obj.getLong(i)); 
          l=1;
        }
        else
        {   
          data_array_string.add(data_obj.getString(i)); 
          s=1;
         }
      }
      if(l==1)
      {
        data_array.add(data_array_long);
      }
      else
      {
        data_array_string.add(data_obj.getString(i)); 
      }
      l=0;s=0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to assign each value in json object based on its type into array lists and assigned those array lists to a 2D array list of type Object. I have to dynamically generate array lists for this. Also when I iterate through json object  I have to check the type of each value. This is taking a lot of time and the code is getting complex. Is there an easier or direct method? Please help me.

Comment: Can you show  your code please?

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. How do you post code in the comment section? I have been trying for sometime but I cant. I tried putting my code inside ' '.

Comment: Please put it in your question. Press "edit" at bottom of your question and fill the code in your question you can format the code on top of your question it has a symbol like {}. otherwise put the code in your question I will format it. Here is a link how to format: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I have added my current method. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use org.json library
Here is the link to Download: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjsonjar.htm
Or for gradle: `compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'`

Then you can create `JSONObject`s like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject()
        .put("user", "user1")
        .put("twitter", "tweet1")
        .put("timestamp", 13661506);
```

or with String:

```
String jsonString = "{\"user\": \"user1\",\"twitter\": \"tweet1\",\"timestamp\": 13661506}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

These `JSONObject`s are easy to handle. For your problem you can easy remove the "twitter":

```
json.remove("twitter");
```

and the result is:

```
System.out.println(json.toString());
//{"user":"user1","timestamp":13661506}
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object with all you fields and then use Jackson API to parse your object directly to the right JSON format

all is well explained on the jackson doc

Jackson allow you a lot of manipulation from object to json and from json to object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.codehaus.jackson`api.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(your original json);
```

And then iterate:

```
Iterator<JsonNode> it = actualObj.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode node = it.next();
    if (!(node.has("user") || node.has("timestamp"))) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```